# How to replace the values of a file by the values of another file?

Tags: bash, file, awk

I explain my problem :

I have two files , one which looks like this (it is a .tsv one, each row has not necessarly the same number of columns) :

```
OTU0001 Archaea
OTU0002 Archaea;Aenigmarchaeota;Deep Sea Euryarchaeotic Group(DSEG);uncultured archaeon
OTU0003 Archaea;Altiarchaeales;uncultured euryarchaeote
OTU0004 Archaea;Bathyarchaeota;uncultured archaeon
OTU0005 Archaea;Diapherotrites;uncultured euryarchaeote
OTU0006 Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Halobacteria;Halobacteriales;Halobacteriaceae;uncultured
OTU0007 Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Halobacteria;Halobacteriales;Halobacteriaceae;uncultured;marine metagenome
```

Each row begins by OTUXXXX and this id is always situated at the first column.

The other file is a .tsv one with 3 columns :

```
OTU3978 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.846
OTU0006 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.855
OTU4929 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.829
OTU4317 UniRef90_A0A011P550 0.85
OTU4816 UniRef90_A0A011P550 0.807
OTU3902 UniRef90_A0A011QPQ2 0.836
OTU3339 UniRef90_A0A011RKI6 0.835
OTU1359 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.801
OTU2085 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.843
OTU3542 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.866
```

I would like to replace in the second file each `OTUXXX` by the second column of the first file. For example, it should give (for the 2nd line of the second file) :

`OTU0006UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.855` which becomes:

```
Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Halobacteria;Halobacteriales;Halobacteriaceae;uncultured UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.855
```

Is it possible in bash?

Edit :

I can replace the columns with that

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' f1 f2
```

But it is not 'automatic' , the first row of the file 1 will match with the first row of the file 2 ... There is not a change according to the value of the `OTUXXX`

Comment: Have you made any attempts?

Comment: Actually, I can replace the columns with that `awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' f1 f2` . But it is not 'automatic' , the **first** row of the file 1 will match with the  **first** row of the file 2 ... There is not a change according to the value of the "OTUXXX" ...

Comment: Please post this `awk` code in your question as your attempt so that it easier to understand what you're trying to achieve and where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. You may be able to use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$1] = $2; next} $1 in a{$1 = a[$1]} 1' f1 f2
```

```
OTU3978 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.846
Archaea;Euryarchaeota;Halobacteria;Halobacteriales;Halobacteriaceae;uncultured UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.855
OTU4929 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.829
OTU4317 UniRef90_A0A011P550 0.85
OTU4816 UniRef90_A0A011P550 0.807
OTU3902 UniRef90_A0A011QPQ2 0.836
OTU3339 UniRef90_A0A011RKI6 0.835
OTU1359 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.801
OTU2085 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.843
OTU3542 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.866
```